# itamae のレシピが bash ではなく sh で実行されてしまう

Tags: rbenv, itamae

itamae を使って新規 EC2 に ruby の環境を構築するレシピを作成中です

itamae のせいなのか ssm-user のデフォルトシェルが sh なせいなのかわからないのですが
execute リソースの際

```
Executing `sudo -H -u ssm-user -- /bin/sh -c cd\ \~ssm-user\ \;
```

というのが頭についてレシピに書いた内容がすべて /bin/sh で実行されてしまい
bashrc にかいた rbenv の設定が認識されずこまっています

レシピのコマンドに bash をつけて実行しても .bashrc は実行してくれないみたいで
毎回コマンド前に rbenv init を実行するしかないんでしょうか
きれいな解決方法があったら教えていただきたいです

追記：

具体的には  itamae-plugin-recipe-rbenv
https://github.com/k0kubun/itamae-plugin-recipe-rbenv
というジェムを利用して

```
rbenv:
  global:
    2.5.1
  versions:
    - 2.1.2
    - 2.5.1
  scheme: https
rbenv-default-gems:
  default-gems:
    - bundler
  install: true
```

という設定で rbenv を /usr/local/rbenv/bin にインストールしたのですが
.bashrc の rbenv init で /usr/local/rbenv/shims にパスが通るはずなのですが
レシピを実行するとそのパスにあるはずの bundle が見つからないと言われてしまいます

ssm-user の ssm 直後のPATHは `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`
になっています
これが itamae 実行時の /bin/sh のときのパスになるかどうかもわかりません）
同じだとすると /usr/local/rbenv/bin や shims がはいってないので見つからないのは当たり前なのですが
どうやって /bin/sh 実行時に rbenv の内容を反映させるのがいいのでしょうか

コマンド全てに bashrc にかいてある

```
export RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/rbenv; export PATH="${RBENV_ROOT}/bin:${PATH}"; eval "$(rbenv init -)"; コマンド
```

というようなことを行えばやりたいことはできそうですがレシピがすごく見づらくなってしまいます
何かいい方法はないでしょうか

Answer (score 1, accepted):

自分でしたら、 rbenv でインストールされたバイナリを itamae から実行するのであるならば、そのコマンドをそのまま実行しようとするのではなく、 `rbenv exec` をコマンドの先頭に付与した recipe で実行すると思います。

例えば、`execute 'bundle install'` を実行したいのであるならば、 `execute 'rbenv exec bundle install'` とすると思います。

Comment: rbenv は /usr/local/rbenv にインストールしてしまって /bin/sh だとそこもパスがとおってないです。あと rbenv init を行わなくても絶対パスで /usr/local/rbenv/bin/rbenv exec をつけるだけで問題って起きないんでしょうか…　rbenv はディレクトリ内にかかれてる .ruby-version をみて shims の中から適切なバージョンの ruby を実行してくれるものっていう漠然とした認識なのですが bundler が何をするものなのか全くわかってなくてすみません。たとえば複数の ruby を rbenv で切り替えて使うとき bundler はすべてのバージョンでインストールする必要がありますか？

Comment: @KTI 絶対パスで、ひとまず問題ないと思います。 bundler は、バージョンごとにインストールすることになります。

Comment: そうなのですね　itamae-plugin-recipe-rbenv のインストールだけでは rbenv local した状態で bundler をたたくと 
The `bundler' command exists in these Ruby versions:
  2.5.1
  といわれてしまったので手動で入れてみます

Comment: 絶対パスだけでは rbenv local 2.1.2 がうまく動かず　export RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/rbenv もつけると一応動いたみたいです。あと bunder 手動インストールして認識されました。他に方法がないみたいなので rbenv の前に毎回環境変数をセットするレシピをかいてしのぐことにします